# How to refresh/reload side input on every window

Tags: java, join, apache-beam, beam-sql

I am using Apache beam to join multiple streams along with some lookups. I have 2 scenarios, If, the lookup size is huge, I wanted the side input to reload/refresh for every record processing (i.e. I will query the database with where clause) and if the lookup size is less, then reload/refresh once a day.

I want to know what is the correct approach for this. I don't want the huge data side input to eat up all the workers' memory.

I have used the below code for refreshing the side input once a day.

```java
PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> lkp =
        p.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0)).withRate(1, Duration.standardDays(1))
            .apply(
                Window.<Long>into(new GlobalWindows())
                    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()))
                    .discardingFiredPanes())
            .apply(
                ParDo.of(
                    new DoFn<Long, Map<String, String>>() {

                      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                      @ProcessElement
                      public void process(
                          @Element Long input, OutputReceiver<Map<String, String>> o) {
                        Map<String, String> map = HiveConnection.getHiveConnection("select * from table");
                        o.output(map);
                      }
                    }))
            .apply(View.<Map<String, String>>asSingleton());
```

Kindly guide me through the best practices for these type of use cases & provide me with some example code for better understanding.

Thanks,
Gowtham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the correct recommended pattern for the small daily lookups.

In the large case, rather than make use of a SideInput, a callout from the DoFn is normally the recommended pattern. This old blog contains an example of the pattern "Calling external services for data enrichment".

[Guide to common Cloud Dataflow use-case patterns, Part 1](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-1)

I will try and find time to add this pattern to the Beam pattern pages at:

[Beam Patterns](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/overview/)